# Draw a graph of an injective function, only given a domain

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

So the math problem is as follows: "Draw a graph of a function that is injective and the domain is (-$\infty$, 2]"

I would know how to draw a graph if there were domain and range, but what do I do with the information that the function is "injective".
Thank you

Comment: it is sufficient that the graph passes both the vertical and horizontal line tests

Comment: It might help if you edit the question to explain to the best of your understanding what makes a function injective.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. It would be better if you post context _e.g._ the source of the problem, what you have tried,  what you know about injectivity and graphs etc. (You can click on the edit button below the post to do so!) Otherwise the post will attract downvotes and closevotes.